# How to avoid certificate prompt when using jboss-cli with a https connection

Tags: wildfly

When I run a command with jboss-cli.sh against a Wildfly server that has HTTPS configured on the management interface, I get the message:

```
Accept certificate? [N]o, [T]emporarily, [P]ermanently
```

How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The solution is to set the `javax.net.ssl.trustStore` system property to the self signed certificate:

```
./jboss-cli.sh -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/opt/wildfly/domain/configuration/https.store --user=admin --password=password --connect --controller=https-remoting://10.0.0.1:9990 -c "deploy /tmp/hawtio.war --all-server-groups"
```

Comment: Does the jboss-cli not use the default trust store?   I would assume adding the self signed cert to the lib/security/cacerts file of the JRE would work as well, though it doesn't appear to be